# How to convert a set of coordinates into a Char?

Tags: haskell

I am now learning how to program with the haskell language and i am having trouble with a code that i dont really know how to write it.

Basically what i have to do is write a function that shows what Char is corresponding to the respective coordinate on a "map" (String). Like so: if i type `function (2,3) ["######", "###.##", "###..#", "######"]` it shows me '#'
and if i type `function (4,3) ["#####", "##..##", "###..#", "#####"]` it shows me '.' .

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? As it stands this sounds like you're asking us to do your homework. (I had a hw problem quite similar to this a few years ago, maybe even the same one.)

Comment: I dont really know what functions to use.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454145/how-to-change-an-element-in-string-in-haskell/33467834#33467834 It's not exactly what you want but could point you in the right direction.

Comment: You can't write code for a problem you don't understand. How would you solve this problem by hand? If you write it down, then you can break the algorithm into manageable pieces that you either already know how to solve, or can ask a specific question about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just give you some pointers:

Hint 1: The list indexing operator is `!!` - `xs !! n` returns the n-th (counting from 0) element of the list `xs`. E.g. [ 5, 1, 7 ] !! 2 == 7.

Hint 2: Haskell strings are just lists of characters - i.e. the string "Hello" is really the list ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']. So `["######", "###.##", "###..#", "######"]` is just a list of lists.

Hint 3: Your `function (2,3) ...` seems to access the 2rd character of the 3nd element in `...`.